# @Transactional and HibernateTransactionManager relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

(very new to Hibernate)
Hi all,

I have configured an HibernateTransactionManager

- If I leave the @Transactional without any params, then the vaues set in HibernateTransactionManager are kept, right?
- If i fill the @transactional attributes, the HibernateTransactionManager properties will be overwritten, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong.
@Transactional params just set params for TransactionDefenition object, they don't cause for HibernateTransactionManager.